# Finalizing WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf

I've never really known what to do after you finish a project in Visual Studio. Normally, I would just take the executable out of the debug folder and be done with it. But after completing my first WPF project, I'm not really sure what to do?

I have all these files in my debug folder:

[image]

I just want to have a single executable file. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [IExpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) is a simple util that creates a single self-extracting package from a set of files. It is shipped with Windows and you can run it directly from **Start->Run**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ClickOnce deployment if it suites your needs. Creating a ClickOnce deployment is a good way to release the software to the public if not the best. It also allows user to check updates, install updates, install the required frameworks automatically (though you as a developer have to configure the bits which are more or less than couple of checkboxes).
You can read about ClickOnce here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=vs.90).aspx

Hope this helps you. If you need any help on this, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Setup Project in the same solution.

1. Right-click on the solution;
2. Click "Add Project"
3. Select "Setup Project" option.

Other tan that, I had good results with [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: Note that this advice no longer works. Since VS2012, Microsoft does not support Setup Project as a project type. You can't even use Setup projects you created in earlier versions. Instead, they have a redirect to have you use InstallShield Limited Edition. Another option is the Wix installer toolset.

Comment: I use VS2010, didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterDuniho it has been added back as an extension in vs2013

Comment: @RobertSnyder: Where? I'm using VS2013 and all I see is the InstallShield project type. I don't see any extension related to setup projects at all (never mind that an extension isn't a project type, but whatever...)

Comment: I should also mention that they aren't kidding when they put the word "Limited" in the name of "InstallShield Limited Edition". It's missing most of the features of even their lowest-end paid product, including Unicode support and custom icons and version resources.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Here is the link https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Comment: @RobertSnyder: great, thanks. It's important to note this in the description: "Please note that this release is a Preview version". But it's certainly a hopeful sign that the preview exists. It'd be nice to have real support for VS installer projects again in the IDE.